# how long do these php settings last, or are they permanent changes?

Tags: php

I've got a couple of settings that I need to temporarily change to run a large script.

**This is a one time deal for importing a large amount of data from an excel document into a mysql database on a dedicated server.**

By setting the following settings, how long do they last?  Do I need to reset them after the process has completed?  If so, what do the defaults need to be?

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

They're only changed while your script is running, and within the context of your script.

Answer (score 2):

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

[source](http://php.net/ini_set)

Answer (score 0):

Please read the PHP docs.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.